# Should an upgrade from Rails 3.2 to 5.1 go straight there or via 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've got a 20,000 LOC project to upgrade from Rails 3.2 to 5.1.

Is there any reason to do the extra work with double handling files to go via 4.2 and get that working before going on to 5.1, or is that upgrade best to just go straight up to the new version?

Comment: Well I did a migration from 4 to 5 and I encountered a few issues. It is advised to go step by step. What is your ruby version ? you probably have to install a new Ruby version locally too (and make sure your hosting service offers same Ruby version). I develop under Windows and installing all gems into a new Ruby version can be very tricky (Curl, curb, etc..). At least check what is advised here : http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html (I would actually follow every step) (BTW the Ruby version change will trigger a few deprecations => error messages => code change)

Comment: @Maxence try using docker instead. Developing on windows seems like a bad idea if you are deploying to linux/bsd and general PITA.

Comment: @max yeah, the mingw32 flagging gems etc it was a headache but I think I am used to it now ^^ I have checked Docker already but am so much into my Ruby code at the moment I can't free up time. But will probably move to it eventually

Comment: Currently on Ruby 2.2.5 so that won't be an issue. I'm anticipating a bunch of work with upgrading gems and finding all the breaking changes in each of them, and undoubtedly having to find replacement gems for some that haven't been maintained. That RoR guide looks good, I'll just start running through that. Thanks

Comment: Anyways its a matter of opion. Going straight to 5.1 might be tricky as it will break large parts of the application and it might take some time before you get your tests back up.

Comment: Thats strange you are running Rails 3.2 under Ruby 2.2.5. They are like 4 years apart.. But if it's the case it's cool. Less problems in sight